# Connected field must be path-connected?

Tags: topological-rings

A topological ring is a ring $R$ which is also a Hausdorff space such that both the addition and the multiplication are continuous as maps.

$F$ is a topological field, if $F$ is a topological ring, and the inversion operation is continuous, when restricted to $F\backslash\{0\}$.

If $F$ is a connected field, then $F$ must be path-connected?

Comment: I never met any connected field other than $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ (and these are path-connected). What are your thoughts about? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Crostul $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: $p$-adic integers are totally disconnected!

Comment: @Crostul Any field endowed with the [trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) is a connected topological field.  Such a field is also path-connected (and utterly uninteresting). That said, I can't think of non-trivial, non-$\mathbb{R}$ and non-$\mathbb{C}$ examples either.

Comment: @Pierre-Guy Plamondon In general, a topological group/ring/field is Hausdorff, here as it well.

Comment: I don't think topological rings (or groups, or fields) are defined to be Hausdorff in general ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring) helpfully gives the example of rings with the $I$-adic topology, which are not always Hausdorff).

Comment: ..In the def'n of a topological group  $G$ it is required that $f : G\times G\to G$ is continuous, where $f(x,y)=x y$ ,  which is not the same as requiring that $f_x(y)=x y$ and $g_x(y)=y x$ are continuous for each $x$. I assume the same kind of def'n holds for top'l rings and fields for both "+" and "x".

Comment: @David Chan . A $T_0$ top'l group is $T_2$. See Hewitt & Ross,Harmonic Analysis,Vol.I.

Answer (score 6):

A [theorem of Pontryagin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334078/are-bbb-r-and-bbb-c-the-only-connected-locally-compact-fields) asserts that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are the only fields which are both connected and locally compact Hausdorff (LCH), and maybe we need second-countability as well. More generally, there's a known classification of [LCH fields](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter5.pdf) that aren't discrete.

Beyond the LCH case it's hard to even get any control on the underlying abelian group. Apparently there are connected topological fields of arbitrary characteristic, though.

Comment: On page 134 of Wieslaw's "On topological fields", there are references for the construction of connected (non-locally compact) topological fields of arbitrary characteristic, e.g. [this one](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250524535), see prop. p. 183. The references p. 47 [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82525113.pdf) might also be interesting.